# Blade echo causes single line string to start with unnecessary new lines?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-4

So I needed to pass a value from my Laravel config file into a Javascript variable.

Somewhere along the line of the standard

```
var data = {{{ Config::get('my_config')['needed_data_idx'] }}};
```

However the console returns that "data" is not defined when I called it another Javascript method.

I checked the HTML and in the header I found out that after (=), it has like four new unnecessary lines that doesn't exist anywhere in the original config value.

How it looks like in the HTML

```
var data = "


1234567890"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put the `var data` inside the script tags, and in the right scope?

Comment: Yes, I added that line to an existing code with similar format, the existing code works fine (it printed var existing_data = "content")

Comment: try using `trim()` function ... `var pure_data = data.trim();`

Comment: thanks, I found out my answer. And for note, the data.trim didn't work since the data variable wasn't initially set properly. I tried PHP trim too but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer, turns out there's a good heap of new lines in my config file before before my opening PHP Tag,

```
//start of file


<?php
```

After I removed the whitespaces above the opening tag, it's printed normally